# How to use drawer in flutter_platform_widgets: ^0.72.0

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to use a drawer with PlatformScaffold but it seems MaterialAppBarData does not have a named parameter for drawer. What is the workflow for adding a drawer using flutter platform widgets for the newer versions. For example in ^0.72.0. I can't seem to find any information on this in the docs or on forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a tutorial using the PlatformAppBar and saw that I should use the material argument in the scaffold other than the one in the PlatformAppBar. Closing this. Below is the workflow.

```
PlatformApp(
  home: PlatformScaffold(
    appBar: PlatformAppBar(
      title: Text("Title"),
    ),
    body: AppContent(),
    material: (context, platform) => MaterialScaffoldData(drawer: Drawer()),
  ),
);
```